# Windows Native application needs receive notification is PC is being used

Tags: windows, api, events, keyboard, mouse

I am writing a C++ appliction on Windows. The application needs to know if the user is uning the PC (they don't need to be using my application).
I don't need to know the keys pressed ... I just need to know that the user is using the mouse/keyboard and they are active on the PC.
Is there an API to register for callbacks?

Comment: Use [GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) and a timer.

Comment: Super @IInspectable - that's exactly what I was looking for